# Getting data from response meta or getting data from item loader. Which is better?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a spider where I am sending some data from parent function to child function via meta. In child function I am parsing these items. But if some data is not found in `response.meta.get('name')` I am writing some xpath in child function.

Which is the better way in these two?

1)

```
item.add_value('name', response.meta.get('name'))
if not item.get_output_value('name'):
    item.add_xpath('name', 'xpath')
```

2)

```
if response.meta.get('name', ''):
    item.add_value('name', response.meta.get('name'))
else:
    item.add_xpath('name', 'xpath')
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid extra work for setting and getting an item value (snippet 1), I would first get the value from `meta` and then check it:

```
value = response.meta.get("name")
if not value:
    item.add_xpath("name", "xpath")
else:
    item.add_value("name", value)
```